# Filtering redundant paths from a list of paths

Tags: text-processing, directory, filenames

I have a list of relative paths such as this:

```
dir1
dir2
dir2/dir3
dir2/file1
dir3/file2
dir3/dir4
dir3/dir4/file3
```

In the example above, the specifier `dir2/file1` (for example) is redundant, because the `dir2` entry would include this file.

Want I want to do, essentially, is remove redundant paths from a given list of paths. The above example would output the following:

```
dir1
dir2
dir3/file2
dir3/dir4
```

Note that the files and directories specified need not actually exist on the filesystem.

I am willing to use any common Unix command (sed, awk, perl, etc.).

Comment: If they do not exist on the filesystem, how can you tell the difference between a file and a directory? i.e. how to include `dir2/dir3` but not `dir2/file1`. (Assuming you have not adopted a such a prefix notation for naming every file and directory...)

Comment: @mr.spuratic It doesn't matter at all... For my purposes, the paths may just as well be named x/y and x/z and it would not affect the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to answer my own question.

I made my own awk script based on @pradeepchhetri's solution.

```
cat data.txt | sort | awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="/";}{
    path=$0;
    for(i=NF;i>0;i--){
        NF--;
        if($0 in paths){next;}
    }
    paths[path]=path;
}
END{for(path in paths){print path;}}' | sort
```

Which works for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the list of relative paths is in file name "path".

You can use the below awk script to print get the desired output:

```
 $ awk 'BEGIN{FS="/";} {arr[$1]=$0;count[$1]+=1;} END{for(i in arr){if(count[i]==1){print arr[i]}else{print i}}}' path
```

Hope you understand how it works.

Comment: Really close. I should've mentioned that it needs to work recursively as well. I will update my example.

Comment: Also, your solution prints out `dir3`, which it should not